# Apache Shiro - Automatically login based on user-agent

Tags: java, filter, shiro

I have a JSF project that is protected using [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org). The login/logout form works well.

However, I need to do the login automatically when using a Raspberry Pi. I can already detect when a Raspberry Pi requests a web page using something like `request.getHeader("user-agent")`.

I tried to implement a WebFilter and do the Shiro's authentication there. It works (code below), but I cannot redirect to the initially requested URL (it always redirects to the login page again, with the user already being authenticated).

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "RaspberryPiFilter", urlPatterns = {"/login.xhtml"})
public class RaspberryPiFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

            String userAgent = req.getHeader("user-agent");

            // If it is a Raspberry Pi, Shiro authenticates automatically!
            if (userAgent.contains("Linux armv7l") && !SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated()) {
                // Here i'll put the login and password for a raspberry pi.
                UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("raspberry", "raspberry");
                token.setRememberMe(true);
                SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(token);
                // Redirects to the first URL attempted
                res.sendRedirect(req.getRequestURI()); // <- This always returns to login page.
            }

            chain.doFilter(request, response);

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

As I said before, the code above works for the authentication (user is now logged in), but the redirection is to the login page again.

Here is my shiro.ini:

```
[main]
# Create and setup user filter.
user = com.apacheshirotest.util.CustomUserFilter
user.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

# JNDI properties
ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
ds.resourceName = java:app/jdbc/shiro
ds.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource

# Realm properties
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT usuarios_senha FROM usuarios WHERE usuarios_login = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT usuarios_role FROM usuarios WHERE usuarios_login = ?
jdbcRealm.dataSource=$ds
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[urls]
/login.xhtml = anon
/app/** = user
```

Is there another way to do this?

**Edit:**

I found out that it is possible to Override the method `isAccessAllowed` in `UserFilter` with something like:

```
@Override
protected boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    if (isLoginRequest(request, response) || req.getHeader("user-agent").contains("Linux armv7l")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Subject subject = getSubject(request, response);
        // If principal is not null, then the user is known and should be allowed access.
        return subject.getPrincipal() != null;
    }
}
```

This works too, but the Raspberry is not really authenticated, right? I'm just allowing it to access the pages, bypassing the login form and ignoring the protection. I'd like the raspberry to actually login, without passing through the form and being automatically redirected to the requested page.

Comment: Don't you think login in with user agent which is so easily spoofable is a very bad idea? What about x509 certificate authentication is it feasible?

Comment: @dev Yes, indeed it is. It was just an example (just to detect if it is or not a raspberry). I'm thinking about something better. Maybe x509 is the way to go (do you have another solution in mind?). I'll definitely take a look at it.

Comment: I have some time ago used X509 using Shiro and I think its the perfect solution. It was the case with some dumb terminals that needed a hardcoded login to the application.

Comment: Take a look at http://meri-stuff.blogspot.in/2011/04/apache-shiro-part-2-realms-database-and.html